# Where am I using the condition that $\gamma$ does not contain the origin

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

I am trying to evaluate $\displaystyle \int_\gamma z^n dz$ where $\gamma$ is a circle not containing the origin with positive orientation ($n\in \mathbb{N}$).

I first calculated $\displaystyle \int_{\gamma_1} z^n dz$ over a circle around the origin and found the answer to be $0$.

Now, let us consider $\gamma$ to be the circle with center $w$ and radius $r$ such that $r<|w|$ i.e. $\gamma$ does not contain the origin.
Consider a parametrization $z(\theta)=w+re^{i\theta}$ of the curve $\gamma$.

Thwn $\displaystyle \int_\gamma z^n dz=\int_{0}^{2\pi}(w+re^{i\theta}).(w+re^{i\theta})'d\theta=\sum_{k=0}^nw^{n-k}\binom{n}{k}\int_0^{2\pi}re^{i\theta}(re^{i\theta})'d\theta=\sum_{k=0}^nw^{n-k}\binom{n}{k}\int_{\gamma_1}z^k dz=0$.

Is this calculation correct and where am I using the fact that $\gamma$ does not contain the origin i.e. $r<|w|$? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If $n$ is always a nonnegative integer, then the integral is zero regardless of whether the circle contains the origin

Comment: @b00nheT, I do not wish to use it because the portion of the book containing that result comes a bit later. Also, I wish to know whether I am learning the subject correctly.

Comment: This computation is mainly interersting for $n=-1$, in which case the binomial expansion will not work, and you will indeed have to use the fact that your disk does not contain the origin.

Comment: For the case $n=-1$, you might want to use the rational parametrization of the circle $t \mapsto c + \frac{1-t^2+2it}{1+t^2}$, where $c$ is the center and $1$ is the radius. Integrating this is then a “simple” matter of real integrals, which you can compute in the usual way.

Comment: @Circonflexe, I may be getting this wrong but even with the parametrization you suggested, the integral I am getting is very complicated.